# Separar una lista en dos listas distintas con strings y números python

Tags: python, lista, string, float

alguien me podría ayudar con la siguiente consulta:

Tengo esta lista:

```
lista = ['5', '1.2', 'b', '3.5', '4', '']
```

Deseo separar esta lista en dos distintas, la una que contenga los elementos en float y la otra que contenga los elementos en string.

La respuesta sería:

```
lista_num = [5, 1.2, 3.5, 4]
lista_strings = ['b', '']
```

Gracias

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Qué has intentado hacer hasta el momento? Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios publiquen sus preguntas junto con lo que han intentado. Lectura recomendada, [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta no es la mas elegante pero te va a funcionar, espero que te sirva:

```
lista = ['5', '1.2', 'b', '3.5', '4', '']
lista_numeros=[]
lista_strings=[]
for i in lista:
    try:
        n = int(i)
        lista_numeros.append(n)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            n = float(i)
            lista_numeros.append(n)
        except ValueError:
            if i.isalpha() or i=='':
                lista_strings.append(i)
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Cuando las preguntas no cumplen con los lineamientos es mejor no responderlas ya que incitan a usuarios a únicamente solicitar ayuda sin hacer ningún esfuerzo y ese no es el propósito del sitio. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me funcionó perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

veo respuestas muy complicadas cuando es algo super simple, te dejo esta función que hace lo que buscas, introduce la lista y te devuelve dos listas separadas.

```
def funcion(lista):
    lista_numeros = []
    lista_strings =[]

    for i in range(len(lista)):
        try:
            lista_numeros.append(float(lista[i]))
        except:
            lista_strings.append(lista[i])

return (lista_numeros,lista_strings)
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Cuando las preguntas no cumplen con los lineamientos es mejor no responderlas ya que incitan a usuarios a únicamente solicitar ayuda sin hacer ningún esfuerzo y ese no es el propósito del sitio. Saludos

Comment: Te agradezco mucho por tu ayuda. Funcionó correctamente. Gracias.